# Natural ways to stop/delay hairloss?

Tags: hygiene, alopecia, hairloss

I'm 28, male, and the hair above my forehead started to fall about 2 years ago and my scalp is finally starting to shine out.

I believe this has to do with genetics etc. but still, are there any natural ways to prevent or delay this?

Comment: Natural way, you mean not including hair transplants?

Comment: No, I mean not artificial medications. I mean something like eat red meat and drink a cup of red wine every evening and your scalp hair will be back on granny kinda thing...

Comment: Male / Female gender identification may be useful here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How to stop or delay hair loss, it mainly depends on your cause and there many reasons of [hair loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hair_loss) (alopecia) as this can be caused by oxidative stress, alopecia areata, an autoimmune disorder, fungal infection, traumatic damage, iron deficiency and many more and it can occur anywhere and at any age.

In general nutrients and antioxidants in food play an key role in body defence mechanism including hair growth. Antioxidants help to neutralize certain free radicals which have the potential to damage human cells and genetic material. They basically halting the oxidation reaction.

#### Antioxidants

- Vitamin C & E

  Is a potent antioxidant that help in maintaining healthy hair. It help to increase scalp circulation and oxygenation.
- Polyphenol antioxidants<sup>[2005](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2569505/)</sup>

  Polyphenols have many health benefits and their antioxidant properties promote hair growth. They're also photoprotective, radioprotective, anti-inflammatory and highly antioxidant.

  See also: [Antioxidant effect of polyphenols and natural phenols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antioxidant_effect_of_polyphenols_and_natural_phenols)
- C60/EVOO (C60 dissolved in Extra Virgin Olive Oil)

  C60/EVOO is an strong anti-oxidant at intracellular level which results in better functioning mitochondria.

  [Studies](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/24021223_Fullerene_nanomaterials_potentiate_hair_g%20rowth/links/0c960528b84a79db7e000000.pdf) in 2009 showed that fullerene nanomaterials potentiate hair growth:

  > In SKH-1hairless mice fullerene derivatives given **topically** or subdermally markedly increased hair growth.
  >
  > The fullerenes also **increased hair growth in human skin sections** maintained in culture. These studies have wide-ranging implications for those conditions leading to hair loss, including alopecia, chemotherapy, and reactions to various chemicals.
  >
  > [...] **We report that fullerene derivatives accelerate the growth of hair in mice and human skin.** [...]

  Quote from Luna [US20110003773](http://www.google.com.tr/patents/US20110003773) patent:

  > Using fullerenes to enhance and stimulate hair growth
  >
  > It has been discovered that **fullerenes can stimulate hair growth**, restore hair growth in areas of hair loss, and induce the formation of new hair follicles.

  Dr. Moussa has [studied](http://www.owndoc.com/pdf/C60-Fullerene.pdf) the effects of C60 on animals for 18 years and claim C60 in olive oil is safe and anti-toxic (has no toxicity effects).

  Quote from one [researcher](http://www.longecity.org/forum/user/19769-turnbuckle/) who was/is taking C60-EVOO orally/topically for over 3 years:

  > Hair regrowth that filled in a patch in the back that had been thinning for thirty years and was bare in a spot about as big as my palm. (A Norwood 4 in the back and a 1.5 in the front).
  >
  > I have now seen further improvement by applying a small amount dissolved in 91% rubbing alcohol, applying it with a dropper to the scalp for a few days. So topical treatment may be better than oral for hair regrowth.

Answer (score -1):

I know that everyone is different, but when I was much younger, I read an article on hair loss and was sold on the notion that DHT is the primary cause. It might also be the cause for you since that "shine" is a direct result of the oily sebum where DHT thrives. So I am now 40 with minimal hair loss and I have always focused on using DHT reducing shampoos. For a long time I used a DHT-reducing shampoo made by Aveeda but it can be prohibitively expensive.

So I did my research and found that Head & Shoulders had the same active ingredients that also reduce DHT. I have been using Head & Shoulders for multiple decades now and I attribute that as being the main cause of being able to have a full head of hair at 40 years old.

Comment: Here on Health.SE, it is common practice and mandatory to **always** include verifiable sources. Please update your answer with them.

Comment: @DMS I personally find H&S to actually CAUSE dandruff. I use Alpohsyl which I think holds back my hair-loss process.

Comment: @Shimmy well, thats fine. The question wasn't about how to prevent *dandruff* it was about preventing *hair loss*. Besides, a dry flakey scalp is usually one with less sebum, which carries the DHT. So a little dandruff might actually be a *good* thing

Comment: N=1 of correlation != causation. Do you have any sources to back up your claims?